# Não consigo acessar o valor de um input de um formulário em uma função FB.api()

Tags: javascript, facebook

Preciso pegar o id de um grupo no facebook que me é passado através de um formulário, de forma que eu consiga acessar dados desse grupo, mas não consigo utilizar esse id na função FB.api(), pois a função não reconhece o valor que é atribuído a 'idgroup' pelo usuário. Dentro da função FB.getLoginStatus() eu consigo acessar esse valor, mas não na função FB.api().

Alguém sabe como eu posso fazer com que essa função consiga acessar esse valor? Já fiquei horas e horas tentando mas não consigo achar uma solução.

```
<script>

        function valor() {
            x = document.getElementById('idgroup').value;
            y = x.toString();
            return y;
        }
        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({
                ...
            });
            FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
                if (response.status === 'connected') {                        
                    accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                    var token = accessToken.toString();
                    num = valor();
                    path = "/" + num + "?fields=feed&access_token=" + token;
                    FB.api(
                            path, function (response) {
                                for (var i = 0, l = response.feed.data.length; i < l; i++)
                                {
                                    alert(response.feed.data[i].message);
                                }
                            });

                    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'conectado';
                } else {
                    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'nao conectado';
                }
            });
        };

 </script>
    <form id="form" method="get"> 
        <input type="text" id="idgroup" name="idgroup">
        <input type="submit" value="enviar" onclick="window.fbAsyncInit()" >
    </form>
   <div id="status"></div>
```